# How to get TextView text from a AppWidgetProvider

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm new both to Java and Android but still have some programming experience in the past (bash, php, C). I'm writing my first widget and I wonder how can I get a TextView's text value from methods implemented inside AppWidgetProvider class. I know how to set that text but is there a way to get it back?

Light

Comment: Could you perhaps post the code snippets related to _setting_ the text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you somewhere have

```
TextView myTextView;
```

you may simply do this

```
String text = myTextView.getText();
```

to get it back.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()